# How to write proper url for ajax if in django urls it is r'^post/(?P<post_id>.+)/$'

Tags: python, ajax, django

django urls:

```
url(r'^post/(?P<post_id>.+)/$', views.get_one_post, name='onepost')
```

ajax:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".answer").click(function () {
        var parent_id = $(this).attr('name');
         $.ajax({
           url: "post/",
           type: "POST",
           data: {parent_id: parent_id}
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: `var url = "{% url 'onepost' post_id %}";`. Here `post_id` should be a variable.

Comment: as mentioned in urls.py  the pattern expects an post_id so change your url in ajax to something like /post/12/ where 12 is th post_id replace it with proper id.